# Color cell in javafx tableview

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I'm trying to color a cell in javafx but I have an error with no suggestion on the following line while trying to adapt the code on Oracle's website to mine.
The line with the error is :

```
 `RH.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getRH());`
```

I have an error with :

```
cellData.getValue().getFeuRH()
```

My method getFeuRH returns a String and is :

```
public String getRH(){
    return RH.get();
}
```

Does anybody know why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `getRH()` returns a `String` and the cell value factory is expected to provide a function evaluating to a `ObservableValue<String>`, you can make this compile with

```
RH.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue().getRH()));
```

However, this just sets the data, it has nothing to do with the appearance of the cell. So, in particular, it won't change the color unless you also install a `cellFactory`.

Comment: Thanks it worked, I have another method in a 'RH.setCellFactory' that changes the color.